# Live search with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I've got 2 views with CI:  Header and Content.

In my controller I load my header, execute a query and then load this into the controller.  This is bringing back all my content.

However, I have a search bar in my Header, what I'd like it to do is when the user is typing, I would like it to filter the content on the page as they type.

Is there anyway to do this without constantly executing database queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you make one database query and cache all the results, and then use autocomplete to query your cache store. Depending on the searchable content this may or may not be feasible. If you have a giant dataset with several million records, it would make more sense to rely on database cache like [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) - if you're searching geo locations or something similar you might want to rely on Ajax API calls to a [Solr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr) instance.

Comment: Thanks.  I assume you mean via http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/caching.html

Comment: If so, do I need to change anything?  The query ran on page load is "SELET * FROM Tbl".  If that query is being cached, does it mean that when it is reloaded it will just use the cache automatically?

Comment: No - you're still connecting to the db when you use db cache. For an autocomplete search filter, you'd want to make one query and cache the results as a JSON object, then use your autocomplete JS to simply search the contents of the local JSON.

Comment: I'm failing to see logic here.  When the page loads the query is executing and it stores the data in a json array which is then formatted using a foreach statement.   How does this current setup differ?

Comment: Right so then point your autocomplete query to your JSON object and not a database response and you have your solution.

Comment: Well that was easy enough.  The issue I have now is that im using a multi dimensional array and jquery autocomplete requires 2 labels that aren't in my array - label and value.  How can I make the statement think that label = Device ID and value = Manufacturer + Model?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717694/jquery-suggested-search-from-json-array/12720262#comment17191919_12720262 :)  Slowly getting there