# Jquery suggested search from JSON Array?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui

I've got a JSON Array

```
json_encode($results);
```

and a search box

```
<form method="post" action="" name="search_form">
<span class="search-text">
<input class="box" name="search" type="text" id="search_input" />
</form>
```

What I'd like to do is search the JSON Array as the user types in the search box and suggest entries.
Part of the array is:

```
[{"Device_ID":"43","Image":"Amazon-Kindle-Fire.png","Manufacturer":"Amazon","Model":"Kindle Fire","Type":"Tablet"},{"Device_ID":"44","Image":"Apple-iPad.png","Manufacturer":"Apple","Model":"iPad","Type":"Tablet"}
```

I know the issue is that AutoComplete is requiring a Label and a Value.  As my array is pulled from a database, how do I go about making AutoComplete think that the label for each item consists of Manufacturer + Model?

Comment: You can try JQUeryUI Autocomplete for such requirements..http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: That's what i've used there, but it doesn't help me concat 2 fields and ignore the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to provide an array of the Manufacturer and Model to `$.autocomplete`'s `source`, use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var devices = <?= json_encode($results); ?>;
    var results = [];
    $.each(devices, function(k,v){
        results.push(v.Manufacturer + " " + v.Model);  
    }); 
    $("#search_input").autocomplete({source: results});
});
```

*That's it. Sorry about my previous complexity, I was basically making my own auto-complete for you, didn't realize you were trying to use the one built into jQuery UI. I've tagged the question with [jquery-ui]*

Comment: So I'm guessing curval is the data typed into search_input with k,v being the combination of Manufacturer & Model?  If so, how would I list that into a new JSON Array as ["Amazon Kindle Fire","Apple iPad"] etc

Comment: Yes, curval is the currently typed value. `k` is the array key (0, 1, 2 ,3, etc) and `v` is the array value (which happens to be an object) so you access it's members using the dot (`.`) operator. See my edit.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: devices is not defined  :/
Is this not going to cause an issue as Autocomplete requires a Label & Value object, my data has none of these

Comment: See my second edit (I modified the `var devices = ` line. I just assumed you assigned the `json_encode($results);` to `$devices`, that's all.

Comment: Yep had adjusted my code to suit it.  I've just realised that its actually the console with the issue. Hit enter on the box and it very quickly shows the results.  Doesn't autocomplete the box as I type though :/

Comment: It's OK, thats what I had just altered it to (almost)  Giving me an unexpected token var error now though

Comment: Ah, spotted the error! Its <? echo json_encode($results); ?>;

Comment: @K20GH Good that you figured out that `<? echo ...; ?>` works, but `<?= ... ?>` is actually valid shortcut syntax meaning exactly the same thing, but it needs to be enabled in older versions of PHP, see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). (I'm assuming PHP, even though that's unstated, because of `json_encode`.) The semicolon in the `<?=` version looks out of place, though.

Comment: Only the code I posted worked.  Not sure why, I'm running the latest iteration of PHP

Comment: Indeed. As @hvd has mentioned, it is valid PHP syntax. I'm surprised it is not working for you because all *AMP installations I've come across have it enabled by default. As the docs state (that @hvd linked), `short_open_tag` must be set to `On` in `php.ini`. If you're running Linux, you can usually find `php.ini` in `/etc/php5/apache2/`, if you're on Windows you can usually access it from XAMPP and WAMP in the system tray. If you're on Mac, google it, cuz I dunno. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar requirement and here is the working code ( /Member/SearchMember is the page which returns JSON array of matching members:

```
$("#name-list").autocomplete({

            source: function (request, response) {

                var searchBy = $('#searchBy').val();

                $.ajax({

                    url: "/Member/SearchMember", type: "POST", dataType: "json",

                    data: { searchText: request.term, searchBy: searchBy, maxResults: 10 },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {

                            return { label: item.FirstName + " , "+ item.Email , value: item.MemberId }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
```